# Why is tension not constant in two ropes but constant in the same rope?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

Why is tension not constant in two (masseless, inelastic) ropes (see diagram) but constant in the same rope?

For instance, if a ball is suspended by two springs— which are attached to, say, a ceiling— the tension may or may not be equal. why is that?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a ball is attached BY two springs". Did you mean "a ball is attached TO two springs"? In other words a ball suspended by two parallel springs?

Comment: Not exactly, i don't want them to be parallel, they make an angle with the cieling. I'll add an image to make my point clearer. I just copied that sentence from my teacher's notes and English isn't my first language so I didn't notice it was kinda unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the ball is exerting a different force on the two ropes.

Assume the ball has mass $m$ and the two ropes are attached at two angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ with respect to the vertical line connecting the ball to the ceiling.

Then, the forces acting on the ball are three: gravity ($m\textbf{g}$), directed towards the bottom and the two tensions $\textbf{T}_1$ and $\textbf{T}_2$ oriented along the two ropes.
Because the ball by assumption does not move, i. e. the acceleration is 0, the sum of the forces must be 0 so that
$$\textbf{T}_1+\textbf{T}_2+m\textbf{g} = 0$$

We decompose it along the $x$ and $y$ directions ($y$ being the vertical direction) and get, on $y$
$$mg+T_1*cos(\theta_1)+T_2cos(\theta_2)=0$$
where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the magnitued of the two tensions. This is because gravity must be compensated by the vertical part of the tensions. On the $x$ direction we get
$$T_1sin(\theta_1)+T_2\sin(\theta_2)=0$$
because gravity has no component along $x$.

From this last equation, you already see that to get $T_1=-T_2$, i. e. same tension but in different directions, you need $\theta_1=\theta_2$ which is not true in general: if the system is asymmetric, the two ropes must compensate gravity by exerting two different tensions because gravity is pulling one rope more than the other! Only if the system is symmetric ($\theta_1=\theta_2$) then the two ropes exert the same force to balance the ball, each one providing half of the force gravity is exerting. You can also see that if you take the limit case in which you only have only one rope at $\theta_1=0$ (i.e. vertical) then its tension will be the same as gravity because that rope must compensate it alone. I leave it to you to find a precise formula for $T_1$ and $T_2$ from the above equations.

When you hear that ropes have the same tension, what it is meant is that, in the limit of a *massless* rope, then the tension *along* the rope is constant. This is because if you take a small fragment along the rope of mass $dm$ then at the opposide side of this points you have two tensions (of the same rope!) $t_1$ and $t_2$ which act on the fragment. This means that
$$t_1+t_2=dm a$$ where a is the acceleration along the rope. If the rope is massless then $dm=0$ and thus $t_1=-t_2$ i.e. along the rope you always have the same tension. Even in the presence of gravity along the rope, the above equation would be
$$t_1+t_2=dm a+dm g cos(\phi)$$ where $\phi$ is the angle of the rope with respect to gravity. Again, if $dm=0$ then the tension is constant along the rope, i.e. the rope "compensates" its tension at all points along the rope itself. If the rope is not massless, then the part of the rope "on the top" has to compensate for the weight of the rope "on the bottom" and the $dm g cos(\phi)$ part would not be zero, making the problem harder: that's why we usually neglect the rope's mass.

This all means that in the example we discussed before, along rope 1 $T_1$ is constant and along rope 2 $T_2$ is constant but in general $T_1$ is different than $T_2$ because the ball's gravity acts differently on the two parts. But because the rope is massless, finding the tension of each rope *at the point where it touches the ball* is the same as finding the tension of the rope *at all points* because the tension is constant!

Answer (score 0):

The tension in each "suspender" depends on the final, equilibrium geometry. For ropes, that depends on the lengths of the ropes and the geometric relationship between the attachment points on the ceiling.

If you have two springs rather than non-stretching ropes, the lengths will change until the  the two horizontal force magnitudes are equal. The final lengths could be different if the spring constants are different.

You can use the basic principle of $$\Sigma \vec{F} = 0$$
to write two simultaneous equations, starting with the *possibility* that the force magnitudes are different. The geometry will determine how the vectors resolve into horizontal and vertical components.